# How to loop two different maps using for_each loop in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-modules

I am trying to attach network interface to backendend pool as per the below requirement

app-poc-1-nic & app-poc-2-nic to app-lb backendpool

db-nic-1-1-nic & db-nic-1-2-nic to db-lb backendpool

Below is the local block with nested map of objects

```
locals {
  vms = {
    nodes = {
      app_node1 = {
        "vm_name" = "app-poc"
        "vm_num"  = "1"
        networks = {
          nic1 = {
            "vm_name" = "app-poc"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/*****/subnets/app"
          },
        }
      },
      app_node2 = {
        "vm_name" = "app-poc"
        "vm_num"  = "2"
        networks = {
          nic1 = {
            "vm_name" = "app-poc"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/*****/subnets/app"
          },
        }
      },
      service_node1 = {
        "vm_name" = "service-poc"
        "vm_num"  = "1"
        networks = {
          nic1 = {
            "vm_name" = "service-poc"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/*****/subnets/app"
          },
        }
      },
      service_node2 = {
        "vm_name" = "service-poc"
        "vm_num"  = "2"
        networks = {
          nic1 = {
            "vm_name" = "service-poc"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/*****/subnets/app"
          },
        }
      },
      db_node1 = {
        "vm_name" = "db-poc"
        "vm_num"  = "1"
        networks = {
          nic1 = {
            "vm_name" = "db-nic-1"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/*****/subnets/app"
          },
          nic2 = {
            "vm_name" = "db-nic-2"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/*****/subnets/db"
          }
        }
      },
      db_node2 = {
        "vm_name" = "db-poc"
        "vm_num"  = "2"
        networks = {
          nic1 = {
            "vm_name" = "db-nic-1"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/*****/subnets/app"
          },
          nic2 = {
            "vm_name" = "db-nic-2"
            "subnet"  = "/subscriptions/*****/subnets/app"
          },
        }
      },
    },
  }
  lbs = {
    tiers = {
        app-lb = {
          lb_name           = "app-lb"
          fip_name          = "app-fip"
          subnet_id         = "/subscriptions/*****/subnets/app"
          private_ip_type   = "Dynamic"
          address_pool_name = "app-address-pool"
          lb_probes = {
            ssh_probe = {
              protocol = "Tcp"
              port     = "22"
            }
          }
          lb_rules = {
            ssh_rule = {
              frontend_port           = "22"
              protocol                = "Tcp"
              backend_port            = "22"
              enable_floating_ip      = true
              frontend_ip_config_name = "app-fip"
            }
          }
        },
        db-lb = {
          lb_name           = "db-lb"
          fip_name          = "db-fip"
          subnet_id         = "/subscriptions/*****/subnets/app"
          private_ip_type   = "Dynamic"
          address_pool_name = "db-address-pool"
          lb_probes = {
            ssh_probe = {
              protocol = "Tcp"
              port     = "22"
            }
          }
          lb_rules = {
            ssh_rule = {
              frontend_port           = "22"
              protocol                = "Tcp"
              backend_port            = "22"
              enable_floating_ip      = false
              frontend_ip_config_name = "db-fip"
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Below are terraform resources that creates  Network Interfaces, Virtual Machines, load balancer, probe, lb rules

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "test-rg"
}
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic-poc" {
  for_each = {
    for vm in flatten([
      for vm_name, vm in local.vms.nodes : [
        for nic_name, nic in vm.networks : {
          vm_number    = vm.vm_num,
          vm_name      = vm_name,
          nic_value    = nic.vm_name,
          subnet_value = nic.subnet
          nic_name     = nic_name
        }
      ]
      ]
    ) : "${vm.vm_name}-${vm.nic_name}" => vm
  }
  name                = "${each.value.nic_value}-${each.value.vm_number}-nic"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${each.value.nic_name}-${each.value.vm_number}-ipconfig"
    subnet_id                     = each.value.subnet_value
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm-poc" {
  depends_on                      = [ azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc]
  for_each                        = local.vms.nodes
  name                            = "${each.value.vm_name}-${each.value.vm_num}"
  admin_username                  = "test-admin"
  admin_password                  = "password@29"
  disable_password_authentication = false
  location                        = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name             = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_interface_ids           = [for nic_key, nic in azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc : nic.id if startswith(nic_key, "${each.key}-")]

  size                = "Standard_B2ms"
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  os_disk {
    name                 = "${each.value.vm_name}-${each.value.vm_num}-OSdisk"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "RedHat"
    offer     = "RHEL"
    sku       = "82gen2"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "lb" {
  for_each            = local.lbs.tiers
  name                = each.value.lb_name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku                 = "Standard"

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                          = each.value.fip_name
    subnet_id                     = each.value.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = each.value.private_ip_type
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "bepool" {
  for_each        = local.lbs.tiers
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.lb[each.key].id
  name            = each.value.address_pool_name
}


resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "probe" {
  for_each = { for lb, details in local.lbs.tiers : lb => details.lb_probes }

  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.lb[each.key].id
  name            = "ssh-probe"
  protocol        = each.value["ssh_probe"].protocol
  port            = each.value["ssh_probe"].port

}


resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "rule" {
  for_each = { for lb, details in local.lbs.tiers : lb => details.lb_rules }

  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.lb[each.key].id
  name                           = "ssh-rule"
  protocol                       = each.value["ssh_rule"].protocol
  frontend_port                  = each.value["ssh_rule"].frontend_port
  backend_port                   = each.value["ssh_rule"].backend_port
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = azurerm_lb.lb[each.key].frontend_ip_configuration[0].name
  enable_floating_ip             = each.value["ssh_rule"].enable_floating_ip
  backend_address_pool_ids       = [azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.bepool[each.key].id]
  probe_id                       = azurerm_lb_probe.probe[each.key].id
}
```

Below is the code I have problem to handle the two different maps using for_loop

```
   resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "pool1-1" {
      for_each                    = local.vms.nodes
      network_interface_id        = [for nic_key, nic in azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc : nic.id if startswith(nic_key, "${each.key}-")]
      ip_configuration_name       = [for nic_key, nic in azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc : nic.ip_configuration.name if startswith(nic_key, "${each.key}-")]
      backend_address_pool_id     = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.bepool[each.key].id
    }
```

Error :

```
Error: Invalid index
│
│   on main.tf line 238, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "pool1-1":
│  238:   backend_address_pool_id     = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.bepool[each.key].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.bepool is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.key is "db_node2"
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Other errors for the azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association resource

```
  Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 340, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "pool1-1":
│  340:   network_interface_id        = [for nic_key, nic in azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc : nic.id if startswith(nic_key, "${each.key}-")]       
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc is object with 8 attributes
│     │ each.key is "service_node1"
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "network_interface_id": string required.

Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 341, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "pool1-1":
│  341:   ip_configuration_name       = [for nic_key, nic in azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc : nic.ip_configuration.name if startswith(nic_key, "${each.key}-")]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc is object with 8 attributes
│     │ each.key is "service_node2"
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "ip_configuration_name": string required.
```

Could someone throw someone light on this ? Thank you in advance.

**Helder Sepulveda suggestion error** :

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on main.tf line 199, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "nic_lb_association":
│  199:   ip_configuration_name   = azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc[each.key].ip_configuration[0].name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc is object with 8 attributes
│     │ each.key is "db_node1"
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the first line in your question you have:

> ... requirement
>
> app-poc-1-nic & app-poc-2-nic to app-lb backendpool
>
> db-nic-1-1-nic & db-nic-1-2-nic to db-lb backendpool

as suggested by @VonC you need a map that creates that relation, I like his approach but I do not like hardcoding that map, instead we can get it dynamically ...

We can see that the vm nodes have `app` and `db` as a prefix same with the lb tiers, I'm going to assume that pattern remains the same in larger dataset, so we can use that prefix to build the map, see my sample code below:

```
locals {
  vms = {
    nodes = {
      app_node1 = {},
      app_node2 = {},
      service_node1 = {},
      service_node2 = {},
      db_node1 = {},
      db_node2 = {},
    },
  }
  lbs = {
    tiers = {
        app-lb = {},
        db-lb = {}
    }
  }

  net_backend = {
    for vm in keys(local.vms.nodes) :
        vm => [
            for lb in keys(local.lbs.tiers) : lb
            if split("-", lb)[0] == split("_", vm)[0]
        ]
  }
  vm_to_lb_map = {
    for k, v in local.net_backend : k => v[0]
    if length(v) > 0
  }
}

output "vm_to_lb_map" {
  value = local.vm_to_lb_map
}
```

I'm simplifying your data to keep the code short, for our purposes we really do not care about the values so I used just `{}` hopefully that does not confuse anyone.

Let's break it down...
I added two new local variables

```
  net_backend = {
    for vm in keys(local.vms.nodes) :
        vm => [
            for lb in keys(local.lbs.tiers) : lb
            if split("-", lb)[0] == split("_", vm)[0]
        ]
  }
```

The `net_backend` loops over the vm nodes and the lb tiers looking for matches in the prefix, *(notice you are splitting by underscore in one but dashes on the other, would be nice to stick to one and keep it standard)* at the end of this we end up with some records that do not have a match...

```
  vm_to_lb_map = {
    for k, v in local.net_backend : k => v[0]
    if length(v) > 0
  }
```

The `vm_to_lb_map` cleans up those that did not not get a match

---

...and a terraform plan on that code will give us:

```txt
terraform plan

Changes to Outputs:
  + vm_to_lb_map = {
      + app_node1 = "app-lb"
      + app_node2 = "app-lb"
      + db_node1  = "db-lb"
      + db_node2  = "db-lb"
    }
```

then you can do the same as suggested by @VonC

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "nic_lb_association" {
  for_each = local.vm_to_lb_map

  network_interface_id    = azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc[each.key].id
  ip_configuration_name   = azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc[each.key].ip_configuration[0].name
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.bepool[each.value].id
}
```

Comment: Dynamic map, nice! Upvoted

Comment: Thank You for the dynamic map example. Now I am getting new error. Update the error details in the question.

Comment: It worked with the below map 

`vm_to_lb_map = {
    "app_node2-nic1" = "app_lb"
    "app_node1-nic1" = "app_lb"
    "db_node1-nic1"  = "db_lb"
    "db_node2-nic2"  = "db_lb"
  }`

Comment: @UdayKiran Perfect! I'm glad you go it to work... remember these are just close examples to your code, you have to fine tune this to suit your needs

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for how to write another for_each loop to iterate `local.lb.tiers`

You want  to iterate over `local.lbs.tiers` and `local.vms.nodes` together, and:

- `local.lbs.tiers` contains load balancer information.
- `local.vms.nodes` contains VM and NIC information.

You would need to create a mapping that relates VMs/NICs to their respective load balancers. Tha means defining a map in `locals` that links VMs/NICs to the correct LB pool, requiring a manual mapping based on your application logic.

Then you would update `azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association`, using this new mapping to correctly associate NICs with LB backend pools.

So, first, that map needs to reflect how your VMs/NICs relate to LB pools. For example:

```
locals {
  vm_to_lb_map = {
    "app_node1" = "app-lb",
    "app_node2" = "app-lb",
    "db_node1"  = "db-lb",
    "db_node2"  = "db-lb",
    // add other mappings as needed
  }
}
```

With the mapping in place, update your resource to use this map for association.

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "nic_lb_association" {
  for_each = local.vm_to_lb_map

  network_interface_id    = azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc[each.key].id
  ip_configuration_name   = azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc[each.key].ip_configuration[0].name
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.bepool[each.value].id
}
```

The `each.key` in the `for_each` refers to a VM/NIC, and `each.value` refers to the corresponding LB pool. That approach should align the resources correctly based on your mappings in `vm_to_lb_map`.

Make sure the keys in `vm_to_lb_map` correspond to the keys used in your `azurerm_network_interface.nic-poc` resources, and the values match the keys in `local.lbs.tiers`.

Comment: I like it! ... but we can do better than a hardcoded map, see my answer

Answer (score -1):

The issue is exactly what the error message says - that key doesn't exist in that collection.

To be more specific, you are taking a key from the `for_each` of the block, which is `local.vms.nodes`, and trying to use it to look up a value in the `azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.bepool` resource set. But that resource set is keyed by a different `for_each` collection, namely `local.lbs.tiers`. So you're trying to look up, for example, `local.vms.nodes["app-lb"]`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Right, I am looking for how to write another for_each loop to iterate local.lb.tiers

Comment: @lxop you are describing the problem correctly, but you are not providing any solution or workaround ... If a user is willing to add a bounty we should go the extra mile

Comment: @HelderSepulveda there was no bounty when I wrote this answer, and the question seemed to be about "why am I getting this error", so that's what I answered